# Jenkins declarative pipeline with mvn, releases and versioned artifactory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git, bitbucket, release-management

We have a requirement to support human defined versions (not auto generated) for patch releases. I'm trying to figure out a way to do this in Jenkins.

We have:

- BitBucket, Jenkins, Nexus/JFrog (either).
- trunk based development with release branches.

  - development happens in `master`
  - when release is GA, create a new `release/vN` branch from `master`
  - while release is under support, bugfixes go into `release/vN`, and are released as patches every week/month.
  - commits to `release/vN` get auto merged into `master` `release/vN+1`, `release/vN+2`, ...
- versions as `v<major>.<patch>`

Want the ability to:

- plan for an upcoming patch by naming it:

  - say current release in prod is `v2.1`
  - we want to communicate to stakeholders that `v2.2` is coming up next Friday.
- build and create an artifact `artifact-v2.2.tar` (/jar/war/..) and push it to a repository like Nexus/JFrog.
- include a text file `build-version` inside the artifact that contains the version `v2.2`.

  - this is so the code "knows" which release is it, e.g. to include in logs/metrics etc.

Problem:

- if we put `build-version` under version control, it'll break auto-merges for bugfixes etc.
- can not auto generate the version during build because it's supposed to be human defined.

---

My solution is:

- change to be released is merged into say `release/v2` branch as commit with `sha-22`
- tag the commit with `v2.2` (= `git tag -a 'v2.2' sha-22`)
- goto Jenkins and trigger a parameterized job with param (say `CHECKOUT_REF_SPEC`) value as `v2.2`
- Pipeline will checkout the `CHECKOUT_REF_SPEC` (= `git checkout v2.2`)
- compile: (= `mvn clean compile`)
- create a new file with tag value (= `echo $CHECKOUT_REF_SPEC > target/build-version`)
- package: pass `CHECKOUT_REF_SPEC` to maven (= `mvn -P"artifact.version=v2.2" package`) to produce `artifact-v2.2.tar`
- push to artifactory.

(I have half the `Jenkinsfile` coded, and can post it here if it helps)

---

#### Question: Is there a better/more-elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried the approach of using [`semantic-release`](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/)? In particular the [`maven plugin`](https://github.com/conveyal/maven-semantic-release) which implements a workflow which would work for you, I think.